# How do I use recursion to iterate through surrounding locations in a grid?

Tags: python, recursion

I am creating a mineseweeper game.

It asks for user input (row,, column) to 'click' on a location in a grid. The number displayed in that location represents the number of bombs in the 8 surrounding locations on the grid. There are regular bombs, which make you lose a life, and proximity bombs, which also reveal all 8 surrounding locations.

I need to use a recursive function to:

- Go through surrounding items of a location in a grid to count bombs so I know which number to put in the location.
- When I 'click' on a 'proximity' bomb, it exposes all surrounding items.
- When I click on a '0', it checks the surrounding items and exposes all other '0's and their surrounding items, for example:

> ```
> X X X X X
> X X X X X
> X X X X X
> 1 1 1 1 1
> 0 0 0 0 0
> ```

Grid = 5 X 5, displayed as

```
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
```

User input asks for row and column, which are then stored in a tuple as a dictionary key. After every turn it reprints the grid, displaying the previous turns which are stored in the dictionary.

This is what I have now: goes through surrounding locations and calculates the number for that location. So if the number is '0', I have to reveal the surrounding locations, who also go through their surrounding locations to check for

```
> def getNum(pos, bombPos, grid):
>     num = 0
>     for i in range(pos[0] - 1, pos[0]+2):
>         for j in range(pos[1]-1, pos[1] + 2):
>             if (i,j) != pos:
>                 if (i,j) == bombPos:
>                     num += 1
```

I have a hard time grasping the recursion concept as a whole and how it could be used in this project. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Recursion is a bad fit for this task, IMHO. Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: For uncovering all contiguous zeroes, try researching the term "flood fill algorithm". Should give you some good ideas.